# gm convert: Unrecognized units type

Tags: imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, image-compression

I try to compress PNG by GraphicsMagick(1.3.23 Q8), here is the command:

```
gm convert -units Undefined -type palette -define png:format=png8 src.png dest.png
```

and it comes with error:

```
gm convert: Unrecognized units type (Undefined).
```

"gm convert -help" shows that units type supports PixelsPerInch, PixelsPerCentimeter, or Undefined.

Acctually, I also try ImageMagick(7.0.1-6 Q8 x86_64),and the command following works fine:

```
convert -units Undefined -type palette -define png:format=png8 src.png dest.png
```

I am confused about the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "+units" instead of "-units Undefined" (this works with both ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick). In general, you can use "+option" to turn off most options. The documentation should be clarified.

Comment: Sock it to them, Glenn! :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works:) The image that compressed use with GraphicsMagick sometimes is larger than use ImageMagick, and larger than the original image. It is my command line question?

Comment: @dodolzg As you observed, sometimes ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick achieve different PNG compression ratios, depending upon the image content.